# How to register / capture location of mouse click inside of terminal on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, mouseevent

I was wondering how I would go about capturing the location of a mouse click inside of a terminal window in Linux with C/C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `xterm`, there are [escape sequences to enable mouse tracking](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking).
But it says:

> The motion reporting modes are strictly xterm extensions, and are not
>   part of any standard

Not all terminals implement something like this, but of those that do, all use the `xterm` escape sequences as far as I'm aware.
But it might be easier to [use ncurses to capture mouse clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11301883/560648).